# TinyMce 4 spellcheck - enchant couldn't find dictionary

Tags: php, spell-checking, tinymce-4, enchant

I've a strange problem with the latest TinyMce 4 spellchecker plugin - it couldn't find the dictionary files.

I've downloaded the dictionaries from the [textmaker repo](https://github.com/mercutiodesign/texmaker-3.3.3/tree/master/dictionaries) and placed them under tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/dicts.

The returned error is:

```
 Enchant spellchecker could not find dictionary for language: en
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I know that i could enable the default browser spellcheck or just use the [nanospell](http://tinymcespellcheck.com/) plugin, but I want to make the default one work.

Comment: @DirkHorsten I think that there is a problem with the EnchantEngine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a dirty solution.

I've just added in spellchecker.php the current DIR path as follow

```
// Enchant options
"enchant_dicts_path" => __DIR__ . "/dicts",
```

I'm not sure if this issue is only specific to my local env...

I've also added some of those dictionary collection https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries (make sure that you rename the name in country-code format en_US, it_IT, etc.)